# Retrofit and GET using parameters

Tags: android, get, retrofit

I am trying to send a request to the Google GeoCode API using Retrofit.  The service interface looks like this:

```
public interface FooService {    
    @GET("/maps/api/geocode/json?address={zipcode}&sensor=false")
    void getPositionByZip(@Path("zipcode") int zipcode, Callback<String> cb);
}
```

When I call the service:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Constants.GOOGLE_GEOCODE_URL).setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient)).build();

FooService service = restAdapter.create(FooService.class);

service.getPositionByZip(zipCode, new Callback<String>() {
    @Override public void success(String jsonResponse, Response response) {
       ...
    }
@Override public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
    }
});
```

I receive the following stacktrace:

```
06-07 13:18:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3756): FATAL EXCEPTION: Retrofit-Idle
06-07 13:18:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3756): Process: com.marketplacehomes, PID: 3756
06-07 13:18:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3756): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FooService.getPositionByZip: URL query string "address={zipcode}&sensor=false" must not have replace block.
06-07 13:18:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:120)
06-07 13:18:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parsePath(RestMethodInfo.java:216)
06-07 13:18:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseMethodAnnotations(RestMethodInfo.java:162)
06-07 13:18:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at
```

I took a look at the StackOverflow question: [Retrofit: multiple query parameters in @GET command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975046/java-retrofit-robospice-multiple-parameters-in-get-command) but it did not seem applicable.

I took the code pretty much verbatim from here: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ so I am a bit of a loss to understand the issue.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

AFAIK, `{...}` can only be used as a path, not inside a query-param. Try this instead:

```
public interface FooService {    

    @GET("/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false")
    void getPositionByZip(@Query("address") String address, Callback<String> cb);
}
```

If you have an unknown amount of parameters to pass, you can use do something like this:

```
public interface FooService {    

    @GET("/maps/api/geocode/json")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    void getPositionByZip(@FieldMap Map<String, String> params, Callback<String> cb);
}
```

Comment: How can add multiple Query params

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra err, by adding more: `void getPositionByZip(@Query("address") String address, @Query("number") String number, Callback<String> cb);`

Comment: its not possible without write any param required ? .. like an hashMap ?

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra not as query params, AFAIK. You could try FormUrlEncoded (see my edited answer)

Comment: For complex query parameter combinations a Map can be used @QueryMap Map<String, String> options

Comment: FormUrlEncoded can only be specified on HTTP methods with request body (e.g., @POST)

Comment: ;tldr(FieldMap isn't good for this)    
The Query and QueryMap annotations are good for appending key-value pairs after the url. The Field and FieldMap annotations are used to put the key value pairs in the request body for a POST request or other request type with body. And it requires the FormURLEncoded annotation as well.

Comment: Wrong answer here,  @FormUrlEncoded can't use with GET

Comment: `@FormUrlEncoded` does not work with `@GET` annotation

Comment: you cannot use `@FormUrlEncoded` with `@GET` request,
Form encoding is an HTTP body and GET does not accept a body.
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1300

Comment: For this url  http://127.0.0.1/TSD/hs/TSD/getturnoverfortheperiod?filter=12.07.2021 I  @GET("getturnoverfortheperiod/")
    fun getPeriod(@Query("filter") filter: String): Call<Nomenclature>

Answer (score 51):

`@QueryMap` worked for me instead of `FieldMap`

If you have a bunch of GET params, another way to pass them into your url is a `HashMap`.

```
class YourActivity extends Activity {

private static final String BASEPATH = "http://www.example.com";

private interface API {
    @GET("/thing")
    void getMyThing(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params, new Callback<String> callback);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

   RestAdapter rest = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(BASEPATH).build();
   API service = rest.create(API.class);

   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put("key1", "val1");
   params.put("key2", "val2");
   // ... as much as you need.

   service.getMyThing(params, new Callback<String>() {
       // ... do some stuff here.
   });
}
}
```

The URL will be called like -  http://www.example.com/thing/?key1=val1&key2=val2

Answer (score 32):

```
@Headers(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Platform: android")
@GET("api/post/post/{id}")
fun showSelectedPost(
    @Path("id") id: String,
    @Header("Version") apiVersion: Int
): Call<Post>
```

**Retrofit** + **Kotlin** + **RestAPI** example that works for me.

I hope this `@Header`, `@GET`, `@Path` with parameters will help someone also)

Answer (score 7):

I also wanted to clarify that if you have complex url parameters to build, you will need to build them manually. ie if your query is `example.com/?latlng=-37,147`, instead of providing the lat and lng values individually, you will need to build the latlng string externally, then provide it as a parameter, ie:

```
public interface LocationService {    
    @GET("/example/")
    void getLocation(@Query(value="latlng", encoded=true) String latlng);
}
```

Note the `encoded=true` is necessary, otherwise retrofit will encode the comma in the string parameter. Usage:

```
String latlng = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
service.getLocation(latlng);
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete working example in **Kotlin**, I  have replaced my API keys with 1111...

```
        val apiService = API.getInstance().retrofit.create(MyApiEndpointInterface::class.java)
        val params = HashMap<String, String>()
        params["q"] =  "munich,de"
        params["APPID"] = "11111111111111111"

        val call = apiService.getWeather(params)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.e("Error:::","Error "+t!!.message)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherResponse>?, response: Response<WeatherResponse>?) {
                if (response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                    Log.e("SUCCESS:::","Response "+ response.body()!!.main.temp)

                    temperature.setText(""+ response.body()!!.main.temp)

                }
            }

        })
```

Comment: Can you put getWeather(params) method definition for more clarity?