# retrofit custom parameter operator

Tags: android, get, retrofit, retrofit2

Is there any way I could use Retrofit and replace the parameter `=` operator sign with my own operator (e.g. `*equals*`).

```
@GET("/endpoint")
Class method(@Query("Key") int value)
```

This creates

`/endpoint/method?Key=value`

but I need

`/endpoint/method?Key*equals*value`

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do a workaround:

```
@GET("/endpoint?key*equals*{key_value}")
Class method(@Path("key_value") int value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100372/retrofit-and-get-using-parameters { } is not possible in parameter part.