# How to pass GET parameters to Retrofit request

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am creating an app with SoundCloud api and trying to append the string value which is entered by user but it showing me null in interface how can I append that in url?

MainActivity.java

```
  b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                search = et.getText().toString();
                Log.d("search",search);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundCloud.class);
                i.putExtra("mysearch", search);
                startActivity(i);

                Log.d("CustomUrl",SCService.CustomUrl);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+SCService.CustomUrl,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Config.API_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

                SCService Scservice = retrofit.create(SCService.class);
                Call<Track> call = Scservice.getTrack(search);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Track>(){

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Track> call, Response<Track> response)
                        {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            if (response.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Track track = response.body();
                                streamUrl = track.getStreamUrl();
                                trackname = track.getTitle();
                                Log.e("track", track.getTitle());
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, trackname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "url" + streamUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //addToList(trackname);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<Track> p1, Throwable p2)
                        {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error"+p2.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //showMessage("Network Error: " +  p2.getMessage());
                            Log.d("error", p2.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            }
        });
```

ScService.java

```
public interface SCService
{
    public String CustomUrl = Config.API_URL+"/resolve.json?url="+SoundCloud.SCURL+"&client_id="+Config.CLIENT_ID;
@GET("/resolve.json?url={SCURL}"+"&client_id="+Config.CLIENT_ID)
Call<Track> getTrack(@Path("SCURL")String SCURL);
}
```

Searched string is in my SoundCloud.java class

```
    SCURL = receivedmsg.getString("mysearch");
    Log.d("intentdata",SCURL);

    tv.setText("Search Results for " + SCURL);
```

I want append that SCURL String in GET parameter but it showing me null value for SCURL, how could i achieve this?

Update: I have changed my code as above but got this error

```
enter code here
  03-15 13:22:14.866 6149 6149 D     search com.sk.scdoenloader                   /https://m.soundcloud.com/dharmaworldwide/houseofcards-mixmaster-05b
  03-15 13:22:14.967 6149 6149 D     CustomUrl com.sk.scdoenloader                https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=null&client_id=iZIs9mchVcX5lhVRyQGGAYlNPVldzAoX
  03-15 13:22:15.299 6149 6149 E     AndroidRuntime com.sk.scdoenloader                   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-15 13:22:15.299 6149 6149 E     AndroidRuntime com.sk.scdoenloader           Process: com.sk.scdoenloader, PID: 6149
  03-15 13:22:15.299 6149 6149 E     AndroidRuntime com.sk.scdoenloader           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
  03-15 13:22:15.299 6149 6149 E     AndroidRuntime com.sk.scdoenloader           for method SCService.getTrack
  03-15 13:22:15.299 6149 6149 E     AndroidRuntime com.sk.scdoenloader           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
  03-15 13:22:15.299 6149 6149 E     AndroidRuntime com.sk.scdoenloader           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:711)
  03-15 13:22:15.299 6149 6149 E     AndroidRuntime com.sk.scdoenloader           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:729)
  03-15 13:22:15.299 6149 6149 E     AndroidRuntime com.sk.scdoenloader
```

Comment: may be you are using your variable before it gets its value .

Comment: You can use Like : @GET("/resolve.json?url={SCURL}")
    Call<CommentMainPojo>getAllComments(@Path("SCURL")String SCURL);

Comment: Got errorNo Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)

Comment: What is receivedmsg ??  In SCURL = receivedmsg.getString("mysearch");

Comment: It's Bundle object for getting string from intent Bundle receivedmsg = getIntent().getExtras();

Answer (score 12):

You have to use **`@Path`** here

```
@GET("/resolve.json?url={url}&client_id={clientId}")
Call<Track> getTrack(@Path("url") String url,@Path("clientId") String clientId);
```

Comment: This one is better solution over the other answer using simple string concatenation.

Comment: Got this errorNo Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1), I have updated the question, where I have made the mistake?

Comment: make sure it belongs to the right retrofit package too. In my case I had accidentally imported an annotation from retrofit instead of retrofit2

Comment: This is the package i have imported "import retrofit2.http.Path"

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: I am using AIDE app, it's included with one progurd file named Proguard-Rules.pro in project directory.

Comment: that is proguard file. reffer this link  http://square.github.io/retrofit/.

Comment: I have added proguard rules but still not solved the problem :(

Answer (score 6):

You can use **DYNAMIC** URL with retrofit !! (With *`@Get`* )

```
public interface SCService{  
   @GET
   public Call<Track> getTrack(@Url String url);
}
```

Then you can call with your *Custom string url*

```
 service.getTrack("/resolve.json?url="+SoundCloud.SCURL+"&client_id="+ Config.CLIENT_ID + SCURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want here are GET parameters, not path, so use `@Query("scurl") String scurl`

More details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100442/541624)

By the way, it's kinda strange (at least in Java) to use all caps for your variable name, `scurl` is more appropriate than `SCURL` here

Comment: I used Asynctask now and my project is completed but thanks for your answer i will try this next time, I made that SCURL as static variable so made it uppercase :)

Comment: I understand that SCURL is a static final of class SoundCloud. However, within the context of `Call<Track> getTrack(@Path("SCURL")String SCURL);` method, it's a normal variable and all caps should not be used ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@Query` here

```
 @GET("Account/RegisterMobileNumber")
 Call<JsonObject> sendSMSToMobileNumber(@Query("mobileNumber") String mobileNumber);
```