# Get users by objectId Retrofit/Parse

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform, retrofit2

I have a list of users in parse.com

I need to retrieve some of these users, I had all of the necessary ids. 
For example I had 50 users stored in parse, but I only need 10.

With these 10 Ids I need to get the users.

I postman I do the next:

```
https://parseapi.back4app.com/users?where={"objectId":{"$in":["id01","id02","id03".."id10"]}}
```

And I get the data correctly.

How can I translate into a retrofit call? How I can do a "where" sentence in Retrofit?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `where` as a URL parameter and setting `{"objectId":{"$in":["id01","id02","id03".."id10"]}}` as the value `textInCurlyBrackets` when using the retrofit call:

```
public interface FooService {

    @GET("https://parseapi.back4app.com/users")
    void getUsersByIDs(@Query("where") String textInCurlyBrackets, Callback<String> callback);
}
```

If you need further information this post may help you: [Retrofit and GET using parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100372/retrofit-and-get-using-parameters)